# How does structure allocate memory?

Tags: c

I'm trying to find out the size of structure variable. As per the code sizeof structure should be 28, but the result shows 8 and name is given more than 20 characters, but it is printed fine. I'm unable to understand this behaviour, can anyone help me out?

Iam using DevC++ to compile my C code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    int identity;
    int number;
}S;

int main()
{
    S *s=(S *)malloc(sizeof(S));
    printf("Size of structure is %d \n",sizeof(s));
    strcpy(s->name,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzffjfjfzdabcdefg");
    printf("name is %s and size of name is: %d\n", s->name ,sizeof(s->name));
    s->identity=10;
    s->number=20;
    printf("Identity is %d and size of identity is %d\n",s->identity, sizeof(s->identity));
    printf("Number is %d and size of number is %d\n",s->number , sizeof(s->number));
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output of "Size of structure" to be 28,but the actual output is 8.

Comment: Because you print size of pointer, not structure.

Comment: Although unrelated to your current problem, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member/119128) should help answer a possible future question.

Comment: And an important note: Writing out of bounds of an array (like you do with that `strpy` call) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)! Never do it! And no, C does *not* have any kind of bounds-checking.

Comment: "... name is given more than 20 characters, but it is printed fine." What do you expect should have happened?

Answer (score 1):

`s` does not have type `S`.  It has type `S *`, i.e. it is a pointer, so `sizeof(s)` is the size of a struct pointer on your system.

If you want to print the size of the structure, you would need to print `sizeof(S)` or `sizeof(*s)`.

Also, you're using the wrong format specifier to print the result of `sizeof`.  You're currently using `%d` in each of your `printf` calls, whereas the proper format specifier is `%zu` for `sizeof`.

Comment: That worked out. But how does name take 41 characters, when its size is only 20 characters.

Comment: It only takes 20, why do you think it takes 41?

Comment: @VangalaUshaSreeReddy  See my edit.  Try changing `%d` to `%zu`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my observation, firstly here

```
S *s=(S *)malloc(sizeof(S));
```

memory is allocated for `s` which is a pointer of structure `S` and printing `sizeof(s)` doesn't result in size of whole structure, it just print the size of *structure pointer*.

If you want to print size of complete structure, either use
`sizeof(S)` or `sizeof(*s)`.

secondly, using `%d` format specifier to print `sizeof()` operator result causes *undefined behavior*. Use `%zu`. For e.g

```
printf("Size of structure is %zu \n",sizeof(*s));
```

Also here

```
strcpy(s->name,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzffjfjfzdabcdefg");
```

`s->name` can contains only `20` characters including terminating `\0` characters & copying more than `size` characters causes *undefined behavior*. Since `C` doesn't perform *array boundary check*, doesn't mean that one should write code which access out of bound data.